# Zoom image where it touched

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I want to zoom that area (50x50 area around it) of image where user touched.

Please note that i do not want to zoom full image.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your image inside a UISCrollView and catch touch up inside event. Then, you can get the coordinates of the touch, and make your UIScrollView zoom on this area.

Edit : As I said in comment, see [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and especially the method `- (void)zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: Can you tell me how to zoom a scrollView at a particular area?

Comment: I let you see [there](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) and especially the method `- (void)zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated`